# Output the Military Order

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

In almost every row nowadays, the people tends to order themselves as militaries would do.

## Challenge

Suppose `4` people where:

- person `1` has priority against person `2, 3 and 4`,
- person `2` has priority against person `3 and 4`,
- person `3` has priority against person `4`,
- person `4` has the lowest priority.

Then, when ordering those `1...4` people in a row, the possibilities are:

```
1
2
3
4
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

*Your mission is:*

Given as input the number `N` of people. Output all the possibilities for `1...N` people in the military order.

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), then the shotest answer in bytes wins!

---

Input can be integer or string, followed by optional newline/whitespace, or an argument to your function. You can assume `1<=N<=10`.

The output should be every sequence in a row, in any order. For each row, output a list/array or any other valid way for the numbers in military order.

Comment: Just so you know, this is extremely trivial in many languages, Pyth for example has a builtin that does almost exactly this. These are just the subsets of `[1..N]` in sorted order.

Comment: So the lists themselves have to be sorted, but can the list of lists be in any order?

Comment: @MartinBüttner. Yes, the order of the list is of your choice. I will update explaining

Comment: Five answers and no upvotes? Come on!

Comment: Please don't downvote challenges just because *some* languages have built-ins for them.

Comment: What military are you familiar with? My superiors would have been livid at the suggestion that the *left* is the higher priority seat/position.

Comment: @Geobits I interpreted it as being front-to-back, with the front being the left of the list.

Comment: @Mego I assumed left-right because *row*. I guess your interpretation could work, but eww :P

Comment: [Very closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9045/31625) I think one of them should be closed as a dupe of the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pyth, <s>14</s> <s>9</s> 4 bytes

```
tySQ
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tySQ&input=4&debug=0)

Thanks [@FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for showing me the `y` function :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I knew that function was somewhere but I didn't bother looking through the docs for it...

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, 41 bytes

```
f 0=[[]]
f n=[id,(++[n])]<*>f(n-1)
tail.f
```

Comment: Could you explain this?

Comment: `[f, g] <*> [X, Y, Z]` is `[f X, f Y, f Z, g X, g Y, g Z]` in Haskell. To form all subsequences of `[1..n]`, I take all subsequences of `[1..n-1]`, twice, and append `[n]` to each element of the second copy.

Comment: Cool .................. +1

Answer (score 7):

## Japt, 5 bytes

(Yes, this is me, ETHproductions.)

```
1òU à
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VfIxIOAgcVI=&input=NA==) (This version has a few extra bytes to pretty-print the output.)

#### How it works

```
      // Implicit: U = input integer
1òU   // Generate the inclusive range [1..U].
à     // Generate all combinations of this range.
      // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 6):

## Jelly, 4 bytes

```
RŒPḊ
```

Basically the same thing as Pyth. `R`ange, `ŒP`ower set, `Ḋ`equeue. [Try it here!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsWSUOG4ig&input=&args=NA)

Comment: I had come up with the same thing, but was rather surprised that Jelly had 2 byte operators, I thought I had made a mistake typing it so I didn't post. Oh well :P Do you know if Jelly is actually out of 1 byte operations?

Comment: Nope, it isn't, yet! But Dennis is still running into features more important to have around than power set... ^^

Comment: `ŒP` (or rather, the function `iterable` it uses) had a stupid bug. `ŒPḊ` should have worked without the `R` (and does now).

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```haskell
f n=init$filter(>0)<$>mapM(:[0])[1..n]
```

The function `(:[0])` takes `x` to `[x,0]`. Doing `mapM` of this onto `[1..n]` takes the Cartesian product of `[[1,0],[2,0],...,[n,0]]`, giving each subset of `[1..n]` with missing elements replaced by `0`.

```haskell
*Main> mapM(:[0])[1..3]
[[1,2,3],[1,2,0],[1,0,3],[1,0,0],[0,2,3],[0,2,0],[0,0,3],[0,0,0]]
```

Finally, zeroes are filtered out from each list and the empty list at the end is removed.

Comment: +1, I forgot `mapM` is in Prelude!

Comment: You have me beat, *39 chars*: `f n=[[z|z<-[x..y]]|x<-[1..n],y<-[x..n]]`

Comment: @recursion.ninja That only gives continuous sub-lists, not all subsequences. It doesn't give `[1,3]`.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
Rest@*Subsets@*Range
```

Composes an unnamed function that takes an integer and returns a list of lists. We need `Rest` because `Subsets` contains the empty list.

Comment: Do we ignore byte contributions from `Slot` and `Function` tokens when scoring Mathematica codes here?

Comment: @IPoiler This uses `Composition` to prevent the need for a `Function`.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 It still does nothing in this form without at least a `Prefix` token.

Comment: @IPoiler like any unnamed function submission, this is an expression that evaluates to a function which can then be used exactly like a pure function written with `&`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I don't see why it's valid to omit `@` in the byte count when `@` isn't considered part of the input format. This seems obvious when you consider other languages are including optional flags in byte counts. What then should be the scores for submissions like `Foo@@` and `Foo/@` which can be applied directly to input? Am I overcounting bytes on my anonymous function submissions by including the implicit `Prefix`?

Comment: @IPoiler `Foo/@` is not a valid submission because it doesn't evaluate to a function object. You'd do `Foo/@#&`. I'm not sure why you'd count the `@`. If you define a normal, named function in a C-like language with `int f(int x){...}` you wouldn't count the `(...)` for calling it either.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I concede that by the tag defaults those wouldn't be permitted but why wouldn't you count `(,)`, `@`, or any other argument delimiters of a language required to call the function? Those are just as fair of syntactical advantages of a language as things like `In/Pre/Postfix` notation or whitespace delimitation such as in bash. Ignoring those seems akin to discounting byte counts from flags, or even arguments which are specified only to use a certain form of a function (ex: step size can't be given for `Range` without specifying the initial value).

Comment: @IPoiler feel free to bring this up on meta, but that's how everyone has been counting function answers for years.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
import Data.List
f x=tail$subsequences[1..x]
```

As so often, the `import` ruins the score.

`tail` removes the first list (which is always the empty list) of all subsequences of the list from `1` to `x`.

Comment: It turns out `f 0=[[]];f n=[id,(++[n])]<*>f(n-1);tail.f` is three bytes shorter! (Do you mind if I post that as a separate answer?)

Comment: @Lynn: no, I don't mind, please post.

Answer (score 2):

## GAP, 21 bytes

```
Combinations([1..n]);
```

Not really a programming accomplishment, but it also includes the empty ordering...

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 18 bytes

```
L]ri{)1$f++}/:$1>p
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=L%5Dri%7B)1%24f%2B%2B%7D%2F%3A%241%3Ep&input=4)

Uses a trick I learned from Dennis once upon a time to generate the powerset.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 42 bytes

```
N->[collect(combinations(1:N,i))for i=1:N]
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns an array of arrays. We simply get the combinations of size `i` for each `i` from 1 to `N`. Because of the way `combinations` is implemented in Julia, the arrays are already sorted.

Example:

```
julia> f=N->[collect(combinations(1:N,i))for i=1:N]
(anonymous function)

julia> f(4)
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 [[1],[2],[3],[4]]                    
 [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
 [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]    
 [[1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 11 bytes

```
2i^q:B!"@!f
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MmlecTpCISJAIWY&input=NA)

```
2i^q    % 2^n-1, where n is the input number
:       % range [1,...,2^n-1]
B       % convert to binary. Gives 2D array where each number is a row
!       % transpose
"       % for each column
  @     %   push that column
  !     %   transpose into a row
  f     %   indices of nonzero elements
        % implicit end for each
        % implicitly display stack contents
```

As an example, with input `3`, the code `2i^q:` gives the array `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`. Then `B!` gives the 2D array

```
[ 0 0 0 1 1 1 1;
  0 1 1 0 0 1 1;
  1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ]
```

and then the loop `"@!f` gives `3` in the first iteration, `2` in the second, `[2 3]` in the third etc.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave, 49 bytes

```
function f(n)
for r=1:n,disp(nchoosek(1:n,r));end
```

This generates the vector `[1,2,...,n]`. Then generates all subsets with `1` element, all subsets with `2` elements, ...,  with `n` elements.

Example run:

```
>> f(4)
     1
     2
     3
     4
     1     2
     1     3
     1     4
     2     3
     2     4
     3     4
     1     2     3
     1     2     4
     1     3     4
     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam (18 bytes)

```
ri)e!{_0#<$}%_&1>`
```

is equivalent to

```
ri)e!_0f#.<:$_&1>`
```

and very different to

```
ri,:)Maf+:m*:e_);`
```

but they're all the same length.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 36 bytes

```
function(x)sapply(1:n,combn,x=n,s=F)
```

`combn` returns all cmbinations of `x` taken `m` at a time. if `x` is a single integer, returns all combinations of `1:n`. `sapply` required to vectorize over `m`. `s=F` stops the results being simplified and thus returns a list as required.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 69 bytes

```
def f(n):print[[j+1for j in range(n)if 1&i>>j]for i in range(1,1<<n)]
```

The key here is that we're really just asking, in order, which bits are 1 for each number `i` in the set of all `n`-bit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES7 proposed), 78 bytes

```
n=>[for(i of Array(2**n).keys())if(i)[for(j of Array(n).keys())if(i&1<<j)j+1]]
```

Based on @MegaTom's binary power set answer. Only works up to n=32.

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 11 bytes

```
,R;╗`╜╧i`Mi
```

<s>This code is super gross. I'm disgusted at how it turned out. I really need to work on Seriously 2.</s> Actually I'm just an idiot. Still need to work on Seriously 2, though.

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LFI74pWXYOKVnOKVp2lgTWk&input=NA)

Explanation:

```
,R;╗`╜╧i`Mi
,R;╗         get two copies of range(1, input+1), store one in register 0
    `   `M   map:
     ╜╧        n-length permutations of range(1, input+1)
       i       flatten list
          i  flatten list
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 92

Saved 17 bytes thanks to mathmandan.

Stupid itertools and its long function names.

```
from itertools import*
lambda i:[y for n in range(i)for y in combinations(range(1,i+1),n+1)]
```

Comment: I think `len(x)` is just `i`, isn't it? So after the `import` statement, how about  `lambda i:[y for n in range(1,i+1)for y in combinations(range(1,i+1),n)]`?  Or better, `lambda i:[y for n in range(i)for y in combinations(range(1,i+1),n+1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 47 bytes

```ruby
->n{(r=*1..n).flat_map{|x|[*r.combination(x)]}}
```

```ruby
->n{
(r=*1..n)         # set r to [1, 2, 3, ..., n-1, n]
.flat_map{|x|     # map and then flatten resulting array one level...
[*                # a golfy variant of .to_a
r.combination(x)  # combination as in combinatorics, conveniently already sorted
]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 50 bytes

A [shorter ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74088/31203) exists, using a completely different method.

This solution uses the unique idea of looking at all the numbers from `1` to `2^n-1` and getting a list of which bits are `1`, for each number.

```
->n{(1...2**n).map{|i|(1..n).reject{|a|i[a-1]<1}}}
```